# Is $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_n^0$ is the first-order part of $\Sigma_n^0$-$\mathsf{CA}_0$?

Tags: logic, induction, reverse-math

This seems obvious in view of the relation of $\mathsf{PA}$ and $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, but I just want to make sure that I'm not overlooking something important.

**Edit:** This is false in view of the fact that $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ can be reduced to $\Sigma_1^0$-$\mathsf{CA}_0$ with second-order parameters (see: https://www.logicmatters.net/2007/09/14/aca0-3-finite-axiomatizability/, also Simpson, *Subsystems of SOA*, III.1.3).

**New question:** What about if there are no free set variables allowed in the comprehension scheme?

The background of this question is that I'm trying to understand what **more** one (implicitly) assumes when one moves from $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_n^0$ to $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_{n+1}^0$. My conjecture was that it has something to do with the sets of natural numbers that one implicitly assumes to exist...